# Firebase Storage completion never firing / being called back

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm experiencing a weird issue when I try to upload an image to Firebase Storage. Essentially I am able to upload the file to Storage, but the completion callback is not happening. I need this callback to get the Storage URL of the file being uploaded.

**SETUP**

```
let storage = Storage.storage()
let storageRef = storage.reference()
let data = curImg?.pngData()
let riversRef = storageRef.child("userUploads/Search/"+id+".png")
```

**UPLOAD FUNCTION**

```
let uploadTask = riversRef.putData(data!, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
    print("FIN") // NEVER PRINTS
    print("DONE",metadata,error) // NEVER PRINTS
}
```

> This doesn't ever print anything

**USING OBSERVE**

```
uploadTask.observe(.success) { snapshot in
    // Upload completed successfully
    print("SUCCESS") // NEVER PRINTS
    riversRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
        print("A") // NEVER PRINTS
        print(url,error) // NEVER PRINTS
    })
}
```

> This doesn't ever print anything

**A BIT MORE HACKY**

```
uploadTask.observe(.progress) { snapshot in
    print(snapshot) // PRINTS!
    if (Double(snapshot.progress!.completedUnitCount) == Double(snapshot.progress!.totalUnitCount)) {
        print("HERE") // PRINTS!!
        riversRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
            print("B") // NEVER PRINTS
            print(url,error) // NEVER PRINTS
        })
    }
}
```

> Is able to print progress and I am able to figure out when it finally completes, but I can never get the downloadURL to complete :(

**EDIT** I tried updating pods and installing all again and didn't help.

Comment: A few suspects. `let data = curImg?.pngData()` is odd. 'curImg' not included in the question. If that's a UIImage, it's shouldn't be optional so the ? is suspicious. But then we have `let riversRef = storageRef.child("userUploads/Search/"+id+".png")` but `id` is not included so we don't know what that is. Lastly, the '.putData(data!' is unwrapping an optional, and if it happens to be nil, the app will crash so that's not a good idea. Can you update the question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you encounter this weird issue, there's nothing wrong with the code. I had to roll back all my pods by deleting `Podfile.lock` using `pod 'FirebaseInstanceID', '2.0.0'`. Weird bug in the latest versions of Firebase / Xcode...?